# Get video thumbnail for song queue discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord, bots, discord.js

So I am trying to get a video thumbnail whenever a new song is playing so when a new song plays and it says "Now Playing: ****${song.title}****" it will also send the thumbnail of the video next to the title of it but I don't know how to do it any ideas?

```js
} else {
    serverQueue.songs.push(song)
    if(playlist) return undefined
    song.videoURL = 'the url for the thumbnail';
    return message.channel.send(`__**${song.title}**__ has been queued`)
}
return undefined
}

function play(guild, song) {
    const serverQueue = queue.get(guild.id)

    if(!song) {
        serverQueue.voiceChannel.leave()
        queue.delete(guild.id)
        return
    }

    const dispatcher = serverQueue.connection.play(ytdl(song.url))
    .on('finish', () => {
      serverQueue.songs.shift()
      play(guild, serverQueue.songs[0])
    })
    .on('error', error => {
        console.log(error)
    })
    dispatcher.setVolumeLogarithmic(serverQueue.volume / 5)

    let embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setTitle(`Now Playing: __**${song.title}**__`)
    .setColor('#FF0000')
    serverQueue.textChannel.send(embed)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use `song.thumbnail`. It will work if you're using ytdl:

```js
} else {
    serverQueue.songs.push(song)
    if(playlist) return undefined
    song.videoURL = 'the url for the thumbnail';
    return message.channel.send(`__**${song.title}**__ has been queued`)
}
return undefined
}

function play(guild, song) {
    const serverQueue = queue.get(guild.id)

    if(!song) {
        serverQueue.voiceChannel.leave()
        queue.delete(guild.id)
        return
    }

    const dispatcher = serverQueue.connection.play(ytdl(song.url))
    .on('finish', () => {
      serverQueue.songs.shift()
      play(guild, serverQueue.songs[0])
    })
    .on('error', error => {
        console.log(error)
    })
    dispatcher.setVolumeLogarithmic(serverQueue.volume / 5)

    let embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setTitle(`Now Playing: __**${song.title}**__`)
    .setImage(song.thumbnail)
    .setColor('#FF0000')
    serverQueue.textChannel.send(embed)
}
```

Comment: this is the embed:
```js
MessageEmbed {
 type: undefined,
 title: 'Now Playing: *Linked Horizon - Guren No Yumiya (Attack On Titan) FULL Opening Theme HQ*',
 description: undefined,
 url: undefined,
 color: 16711680,
 timestamp: null,
 fields: [],
 thumbnail: null,
 image: { url: undefined },
 video: null,
 author: null,
 provider: null,
 footer: null,
 files: [] 
}
```

Comment: Can you log `song` please?

Comment: i will log it, what do you want me to execute and where do i put the log?